# How do action spaces of stable_baselines3's A2C model work?

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, stable-baselines

I'm trying to build an A2C model to play chess using `python-chess` and `stable_baselines3` Python libraries, but my model is not showing much progression even after 100k training games. I'm using a custom environment `ChessEnvironment()` that inherits from `gymnasium.Env`, and I think the problem has something to do with how I'm building the action space. Briefly here's my imports

```
import chess
import re
import gymnasium as gym
import numpy as np
from stable_baselines3 import A2C
from stable_baselines3.common.policies import ActorCriticPolicy
from torch.nn import ReLU
```

and relevant code snippets starting with one from my custom environment's init function:

```
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    # Representing board as a 1-hot encoded 8x8 grid
    self.observation_space = gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=1, shape=(8, 8, 12), dtype=np.uint8)
    # Initialize the chessboards
    self.board = chess.Board()
    self.last_board = self.board
    # Action space 
    self.move_dict = make_move_list(self.board)
    self.action_space = gym.spaces.Discrete(len(self.move_dict))

    # ... Some more parameters ...

    # Policy kwargs for A2C model
    self.policy_kwargs = dict(
        net_arch=dict(pi=[128, 128, 64], vf=[128, 128, 64]),
        activation_fn=ReLU,
    )
```

In addition, here's my step function in full:

```
def step(self, action):
    move = self.move_dict[action]
    self.move_list.append(move)
    # Save the board as is before making the move for reward calculation
    self.last_board = self.board
    # Execute the specified action on the chessboard
    self.board.push_san(move)
    self.sync_action_space()

    # Convert the board to the observation format
    observation = np.zeros((8, 8, 12), dtype=np.uint8)
    for square, piece in self.board.piece_map().items():
        piece_type = piece.piece_type
        piece_color = int(piece.color)
        observation[square // 8][square % 8][piece_type - 1 + 6 * piece_color] = 1


    # Calculate the reward
    reward = self.calculate_reward()
    # Check if the episode is done
    terminated = (self.board.result() != '*')
    # Return the observation, reward, done flag, and additional info
    return observation, reward, terminated, False, {}
```

I'm not entirely sure why my model does poorly (ie the model after 100k games performs about the same as it did after 10k games). My best guess is that the problems stem from how the action space is recreated with each position--the `sync_action_space` function that is called after the move is made in the step function is as follows

```
def sync_action_space(self):
    self.move_dict = make_move_list(self.board)
    self.action_space = gym.spaces.Discrete(len(self.move_dict))
```

where `make_move_list` just queries the board object for all legal moves given the state and puts them into a dictionary. Am I correct in thinking that the model's failure to learn is (or at least is majorly influenced by) an inadequate action space? Or should I mess around with hyperparameters more (I also have weights for the different heuristics of my reward function that I can tweak)? Thanks in advance